# How can I group form elements

Tags: php, html, forms

I got this form:

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="utf-8"> 
<p>
  <label>first_field</label><br />
  <input type="text" id="first_field" name="points[]" /><br />
  <input type="radio" value="inside" name="group_1" checked /><br />
  <input type="radio" value="outside" name="group_1"><br />
</p>
<p>
  <label>second_field</label><br />
  <input type="text" id="second_field" name="points[]" /><br />
  <input type="radio" value="inside" name="group_2" checked /><br />
  <input type="radio" value="outside" name="group_2"><br />
</p>
</form>
```

What i want to accomplish is to check if inside or outside is checked, if outside i checked the multiply points for the given text input by 1,5. BTW this needs to be calculated in PHP.

How can I do that?

### UPDATE

```
Array
(
[bonus] => Array
    (
        [points] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 0
                [2] => 0
                [3] => 0
                [4] => 0
                [5] => 0
                [6] => 0
                [7] => 0
                [8] => 0
                [9] => 0
                [10] => 0
                [11] => 0
                [12] => 0
                [13] => 0
                [14] => 0
            )

        [group] => Array
            (
                [0] => inside
                [1] => outside
                [2] => outside
                [3] => inside
                [4] => inside
                [5] => inside
                [6] => inside
                [7] => inside
                [8] => outside
                [9] => inside
                [10] => inside
                [11] => inside
                [12] => outside
                [13] => inside
                [14] => inside
            )

    )

)
```

Above is the result of print_r($_POST)

Now ho do I compare/pare The points array with the Group array so:

points[0] gets "connected" to group[0] etc.?

Comment: For more semantic mark up, use the <fieldset> tag instead of those <p> tags, and use <legend> instead of <label> for those titles.

Comment: Definitely don't use label to label groups of fields. A label is associated with a single field (which either needs to be a child of the label, or referenced with a for attribute)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

As it turns out, you can group fields using HTML forms. Check out this code here: (specifically note the `name` attributes)

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="utf-8">
<p>
  <label>first_field</label><br />
  <input type="text" id="first_field" name="field[1][points]" /><br />
  <input type="radio" value="inside" name="field[1][group]" checked /><br />
  <input type="radio" value="outside" name="field[1][group]"><br />
</p>
<p>
  <label>second_field</label><br />
  <input type="text" id="second_field" name="field[2][points]" /><br />
  <input type="radio" value="inside" name="field[2][group]" checked /><br />
  <input type="radio" value="outside" name="field[2][group]"><br />
</p>
</form>
```

Without filling anything in, this will yield a POST array like this:

```
Array
(
    [field] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [points] => 
                    [group] => inside
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [points] => 
                    [group] => inside
                )

        )
)
```

I hope this answered your question, it's a neat little trick I haven't really seen many others discuss. One thing to note is that you'll need to manually specify an ID number in that any set of brackets. You can only use `[]` as the last set of brackets.

Comment: Thank you Dominic, that was what I where looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I'm expanding on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5806722/3954106) because it took me a while to track down the PHP code that would parse the data from the form.

Using this technique in HTML will result in a key-value pair array.

```
  <input type="text" id="first_field" name="field[1][points]" /><br />
  <input type="radio" value="inside" name="field[1][group]" checked /><br />
  <input type="radio" value="outside" name="field[1][group]"><br />
```

This is how I used PHP to parse the array.

```
foreach ($_POST as $record => $detail) {
// The submit button from my HTML form was POSTing data
// so I used an if statement to remove it from the result set
if(empty($firstRow))
{
    $firstRow = 1;
}
else
{
    // since $detail is still an array, you have to loop through it again
    foreach ($detail as $key => $value) {
            echo $key."<br/>";
            // $key would contain the key value (1 or 2)
            echo $value['points']."<br/>";
            echo $value['group']."<br/><br/>";
    }
}

}
```

Hope this answer helps!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to catch what it coming back in the `$_POST` variable, and process it. If you do a `var_dump($_POST)` after completing your form, you should have a better idea of what to do.

Comment: or print_r($_post) with a <pre> tag :)