# Web2py comparing part of a request.vars element

Tags: python, variables, request, substring, web2py

I have a form with a table with rows containing SELECTs with _names with IDs attached, like this:

```
TD_list.append(TD(SELECT(lesson_reg_list, _name='lesson_reg_' + str(student[4]))))
```

When the form is submitted I want to extract both the student[4] value *and* the value held by request.vars.lesson_reg_student[4].

I've tried something like:

```
for item in request.vars:
    if item[0:9] == "lesson_reg":
        enrolment_id = int(item[10:])
        code = request.vars.item
```

I also tried treating request.vars like a dictionary by using:

```
for key, value in request.vars:
    if key[0:9] == "lesson_reg":
        enrolment_id = int(key[10:])
        code = value
```

but then I got 'too many values to unpack'. How do I retrieve the value of a request.vars item when the last part of its name could be any number, plus a substring of the item name itself?

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: It's a good idea to explain what's wrong with your current approach -- in other words, describe what output (including any errors) you are seeing and what you expect instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, when slicing, the ending index is *excluded*, so your two slices should be `0:10` and `0:11`. To simplify, you can also use `.startswith` for the first one:

```
for item in request.vars:
    if item.startswith('lesson_reg'):
        enrolment_id = int(item[11:])
        code = request.vars.item
```

Comment: Of course! Thanks so much, that did it. I didn't know about.startswith either, brilliant.