# How to group form data with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a bit of code that creates a dynamic input and select:

```
<div v-for="(index) in rows">
    <select>
        <option selected="true" disabled>Select Type</option>
        <option>Name</option>
        <option>Address</option>
        <option>Email</option>
        <option>Phone</option>
        <option>Medical</option>
        <option>Tax File Number</option>
        <option>Card Number</option>
        <option>Financial Card</option>
        <option>Medical Card</option>
        <option>Social Card</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" list="predictive_data" class="uk-input">
</div>

<button v-on:click="addRow" type="button">Add Input</button>
```

This works great, but my issue is that I would like to somehow group the inputs. If there are multiple names and multiple emails, when it gets sent to my Flask backend, I can see whose data is whose.

Currently, if I were to add 3 names and 1 email, it arrives at my backend like this:

```
Name:['John Smith', 'Jane Doe', 'Bob Alan'], Email:[coolkid69@email.com]
```

As you can see, I can't tell who owns the email. I'd prefer it like this:

```
{Name:'John Smith'}, {Name:'Jane Doe', Email:'coolkid69@email.com'}, {Name:'Bob Alan'}
```

Comment: Add a `button` that says `StartFormGroup` and then there you add all inputs then the user could click on `StartNewGroup` and then add another group of input etc. Create an online(fiddler) vue of your application i could make a change to it and show you.

Comment: can you also provide how you retrieve data and send data to backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML form encoding (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) doesn't support arrays of objects like that. Some backends ([Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5806722/6277151) or [Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34753224/6277151)) support special key-naming in the form data to group complex objects, but Flask does not (at least not out of the box).

I think the easiest solution is for the Vue client to send the form data as JSON in the desired format, and the Flask backend to receive it as JSON (i.e., [`request.get_json()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.get_json) instead of `request.form`).

1. Break up your groups into `rows`, where each `row` contains a label and value respectively bound to a `<select>.v-model` and `<input>.v-model`:

   ```
   // MyForm.vue template
   <fieldset v-for="group in groups" :key="group.id">
     <div v-for="row in group.rows" :key="row.id">
       <select v-model="row.label">...</select>
       <input type="text" v-model="row.value">
     </div>
     <button type="button" @click="addRow(group)">Add Input</button>
   </fieldset>

   // MyForm.vue script
   data() {
     return {
       groups: [
         {
           id: 1,
           rows: [{ id: 1, label: "Name", value: "John Doe" }]
         },
         {
           id: 2,
           rows: [
             { id: 2, label: "Name", value: "Jane Doe" },
             { id: 3, label: "Email", value: "coolkid69@email.com" }
           ]
         },
         {
           id: 3,
           rows: [{ id: 4, label: "Name", value: "Bob Alan" }]
         }
       ]
     };
   }
   ```
2. Add a `submit` method to post your specially formatted data:

   ```
   // MyForm.vue script
   methods: {
     submit(e) {
       const formData = this.groups.map(group => group.rows.reduce((c, row) => {
         c[row.label] = row.value;
         return c;
       }, {}));

       axios.post(e.target.action, formData);
     }
   }
   ```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/qgzRyj?editors=1010)